# bootstrap 3 z-index place a div over another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I'm trying to place a div over another div in bootstrap , I didn't change any css of bootstrap so all the code below is bootstrap no custom css added.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 listing-panel side-bar-for-single-listing" style="margin-top: 10px;">

      <div class="col-lg-12" style="z-index: 999; background: red; height: 40%;">   </div>  

        <form class="col-lg-12" style=" ">

            <legend>Contact</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="IDinputName">Name*</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="IDinputName" placeholder="Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="IDinputMobile">Mobile*</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="IDinputMobile" placeholder="Mobile" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="IDinputMessage">Message*</label>
                <textarea id="IDinputMessage" class="form-control" style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
            </div>



            <button type="submit" id="IDcontactSubmitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>

        </form>

    </div>
```

here is what I'm currently having I want the red box to cover 100% of the form element  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this! I hope it can help! :)

```html
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; z-index: -1; right: 0px; margin: 0px auto;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have make position absolute of div which has z-index

```
 <div class="col-lg-12" style="**position:absolute**;z-index: 999; background: red; height: 40%;">   </div>
```